# How to access a CTE column in sqlalchemy filter()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query object with two columns: one is a real column from a table, the other is aggregate.

The query object is returned by a function and used later in the code.

```
def thequery():
    cte1 = (
        db.query(
            UserFile.user_id, 
            func.min(UserFile.id).label("min_id")
        ).group_by(UserFile.user_id)
    ).cte("cte1")

    return db.query(User.name, cte1.c.min_id).join(cte1, cte1.c.user_id == User.id)
```

Since the query is not yet executed, I can add more filters.

```
q = thequery()
q.filter(User.name == "John")  # This works because `User` is a model.
```

However, I can't find a way to filter by my CTE column.

```
q.filter(min_id == 200)  # How to refer to min_id?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import literal_column
q.filter(literal_column("cte1.min_id") == 200)
```

You can use expression above